# Error 6124 with Word automation

Tags: ms-word, office-automation

Why do I get an `"Error 6124: You are not allowed to edit this section because it is protected."` when running this code on certain machines?   I do not get it on my development machine.  The bookmarks are associated with form fields.

```
Set objWordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set oDoc = objWordApp.Documents.Open(strDocPath)
oDoc.bookmarks("CustomerName").Select
objWordApp.selection = "Mr Smith"
oDoc.bookmarks("CustomerNumber").Select
objWordApp.selection = "0001"
oDoc.save
oDoc.Bookmarks("Comments").Select
oDoc.ActiveWindow.View = 1
objWordApp.WindowState = 0
objWordApp.Visible = True
oDoc.Activate
objWordApp.Activate
```

Comment: Precisely what type of protection have you applied? Is it the usual "Allow only this type of editing - Filling in Forms" or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a protected/restricted document you need to refer to `.FormFields` instead of `.Bookmarks`.

Instead of:

```
oDoc.Bookmarks("CustomerName").Select
objWordApp.selection = "Mr Smith"
```

Use:

```
oDoc.FormFields("CustomerName").Result = "Mr Smith"
```

Comment: But why do you think this causes a problem on some machines and not others?

Comment: I don't know. At a guess it might be something to do with user permissions.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue as the original poster. One user got the 6124 error while other users didnt. I tried the suggestions above but none fixed the issue. What worked for me was resetting Word to its original settings using the quick fix in this [MS article.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/word/reset-options-and-settings-in-word)

Hope it helps someone else!

Answer (score 0):

Open the document in question. Go to File->Options->General. Untick the box "Open e-mail attachments and other uneditable files in reading view"

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-word/run-time-error-4605-in-word-2013-no-information/1ca02c04-5cea-484e-bd23-f4d18183c1b2?auth=1

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error. It took a while to figure it out but the file permissions (in Windows) was set to Read-only.

In Windows Explorer, Right-click on the file and choose properties. 
Then un-check the Read-only checkbox on the General Tab.